# Stored procedure and Xamarin

Tags: web-services, stored-procedures, xamarin

I am trying to call a stored procedure from a Xamarin app, the app will just be a simple create operation, so the stored procedure will only take in parameters. Any idea how to do the connection or put the stored procedure in a web service or something? Any resources would be much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Where is your stored procedure? (in this database or server-side logic?)

You can use RESTful Web Service. It is [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/rest/). It is [example](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/).

This is general information. Details depend on how backebd you are using. I use [Azure mobile app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop/).

Comment: It is in a database, i will be using Azure App Service, Thank you for the information i guess i am better off learning Restful Web Service and forget about store procedures x) or maybe later i'll know how to manipulate it and pass the Stored procedure itself as a RESTful Web Service.

Comment: It is example use stored procedure from .NET Backend - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/writingdata_services/2014/09/04/exposing-a-stored-procedure-in-a-net-backend-mobile-service/